# Django: How to receive QuerySet with $getJSON in Jquery or $http.get in Angular.js?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, django, angularjs

In ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Api, I can receive data list in jQuery or Angular.js if my C# code like below:

`return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

I'm newbie to Django so I don't know how to write in backend if I want to receive the list in my front page.

### `jQuery:`

```
$.getJSON(url, function (list) {
    result=list
};
```

or

### `Angular.js:`

```
$http.get(url).success(function(list) {
    result=list
};
```

My Model

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Assume that there are two polls in database, 
I have tried 3 situations in views.py.

```
list = Poll.objects.all()
```

1.
`return HttpResponse(list)`

What I get in jQuery callback or Angular callback will be **"Poll objectPoll object"**.

2.
`return HttpResponse(list.values())`

I will get SyntaxError: **" Unexpected token ' "**

3.
`return HttpResponse(list.values_list())`

I will get a string(it also seems not in json):

```
"(1, u'Which city is the most beautiful all over the world?', datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 19, 7, 8, tzinfo=<UTC>))(2, u'What is your favourite city?', datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 19, 7, 8, 43, tzinfo=<UTC>))"
```

But In ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Api, even I return json list in backend(C#), I always get deserialized list in my js callback, so I can use it directly.

Did I use wrong APIs of QuerySet or wrong List Type?

Thanks in advance.

---

***Edit to add info when I tried some answers:***

Thanks for the detail answer, but I get **"datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 19, 7, 8, tzinfo=) is not JSON serializable"** if I use:
`return HttpResponse(json.dumps([poll.dict for poll in Poll.objects.all() ]))`

Then I change my code to 
`return HttpResponse(json.dumps(Poll.objects.values(), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))` 
but what I get is **"[{'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 19, 7, 8, tzinfo=), 'question': u'Which city is the most beautiful all over the world?', u'id': 1}, {'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 19, 7, 8, 43, tzinfo=), 'question': u'What is your favourite city?', u'id': 2}] is not JSON serializable"**.

After googled, I change my code to 
`return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', Poll.objects.all()))`
 This time is no error in js callback, but the received data structure liked below:

`Array[2]
0: Object
  fileds: Object
    pub_date:...
    question:...
  model: "polls.poll"
  pk: 1
1: Object
  fileds: Object
    pub_date:...
    question:...
  model: "polls.poll"
  pk: 2`

What should I do if I want to get:

`Array[2]
0: Object
  id: 1
  question:...
  pub_date:...
1: Object
  id: 2
  question:...
  pub_date:...`

Answer (score 1):

You would do it slightly different in Python/Django.

Now, for queryset, `.values()` has a different meaning. [You can read about it here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values)

> Returns a ValuesQuerySet — a QuerySet subclass that returns dictionaries when used as an iterable, rather than model-instance objects.

To achieve what you are looking for, you need the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) that python provides.

In the model `Poll`:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    #attributes
    def to_json(self):
        return {'field1': 'attribute1', ... } #if you want a subset of all the attributes
```

and in the views:

```
polls = Poll.objects.all()
return HttpResponse(json.dumps([poll.to_json() for poll in polls ]))
```

Now, if you want **all** the attributes, you can just do:

```
polls = Poll.objects.all()
return HttpResponse(json.dumps([poll.__dict__ for poll in polls ]))
```

Also, do not use `list` as a local variable name, as it conflicts with the builting type.

Comment: I edited the original question according to your answer, please have a look. :)

Comment: why do you want it in that specific format? As long as you can parse the correct json, why would you be concerned ?

Comment: you mean the data structure what I received in js callback? because I don't want to change the code in js callback if the js code is migrated for other background such as ASP.NET MVC, I want to use the data list return from backend with normal model structure. And finally, I changed the return code to **return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(poll_list.values()), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))** and got desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(Poll.objects.all()), 
                    content_type="application/json")
```

The above uses `json` to serializes your queryset.  I'm not sure if there are some model fields that could choke when being serialized, so you might want to look at bulit in [django serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)

---

if you have many API endpoints, I would recommend looking at [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: Yes, the DateTimeField can't be serialized. I edited the original question, please have a look. By the way, this is only a example project for me to study Django, so I don't want to use another framework such as django-rest-framework. :)

Comment: I would say not using django-rest-framework would be a huge mistake.  It's tantamount to saying, I want to go fast, but I don't want to use wheels, or wings, or an engine.